# How to embed WMV files in my html5 file

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to embed some s3 WMV file urls in my html page, but the code below is not working.

```
<object classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsm p2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112"> 
    <param name="fileName" value="http://www.ladieda.com/mymovie.wmv"> 
    <param name="autoStart" value="false"> 
    <param name="showControls" value="true"> 
    <param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="true"> 
    <param name="ClickToPlay" value="true"> 
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="http://www.ladieda.com/mymovie.wmv" autoStart="false" ></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: You should use `ffmpeg` or comparable tool, and convert them to a supported format: mp4, webm, or ogg. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: is there anyway i can embed them without converting them?

Comment: No. I don't think even the Microsoft web browser supports that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be because nearly every browser does not support WMV as a type of file. Aside from IE, this type of format is unlikely to be compatible with most browsers.

Find an online file converter which the file format to WMV to Mp4 or something else.

**This might help:**

http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4

Comment: converting the video and embedding it would definitely work but want to know if there is any way i can embed wmv file itself

Answer (score 1):

As L.S said most web browsers do not support WMV files, however services like https://vid.me/ allow for you to upload WMV files for free and using their embed code you may be able to resolve this issue.

Hope this helps!